# Does "business-speak" belong in [business-language]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[business-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-language) has the following tag wiki:

> There are very many specialized terms and communication conventions
>   related to doing business in English. This tag covers questions about
>   those topics, including any of the following:
>
> - The meaning of a specialized term used in management, commerce, or industry
> - Whether a given word or idiom has an appropriate level of formality for use in business communication
> - Whether a piece of industry jargon is likely to be understood by members of the general public
>
> Questions in this tag should generally involve terms that are used
>   across multiple companies and industries. Questions about jargon
>   that's specific to a particular company or a single narrow
>   specialization are likely to be closed as "too localized".

The portion "Whether a given word or idiom has an appropriate level of formality for use in business communication" seems to concern using language that is formal, and I assume prescriptively correct, English. I can see near-fluent learners of English wanting to use this to know how to look professional.

But the other portions of the wiki, about jargon, seem to cover "business-speak", which includes some heavily criticised practises including the nouning of a large number of verbs and some controversial metaphors.

Does business-speak belong in the tag business-language?

Comment: I tried coming up with a business-speak title for this, but the only one I could think of was "Can we be open kimono about [business-language]?", which is a little gross.

Comment: I would prefer not to answer "is this email to my boss formal enough?" questions at all. They're subjective (aka POB), localized (who knows *your* boss and workplace environment?), and if we let them in they'll absolutely *litter* the site. Further, a vast swath of such questions which *are* asked are based on false premises, as many non-native speakers misconstrue contemporary Western business culture and believe it to be much more formal and explicitly hierarchical than it actually is.

Comment: Is this a Meta question or are you using the tag as a metaphor?

Answer (score 1):

I take your reference to 'business-speak' to be limited to those instances that have gained broad acceptance.

Unlike the questions about email that Dan Bron's [comment](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7927/does-business-speak-belong-in-business-language#comment32748_7927) refers to, which are off topic on *opinion* or *proofreading* grounds, questions about 'business-speak' are about established English terms. Also, unlike some lit. crit., where meaning is subjective, 'business-speak' terminology *must* have established meaning, or else they would have already failed as 'business-speak'.

'Business-speak' should therefore be treated as figures of speech, or at least granted the same courtesies as questions about region-specific turns of phrase.

> Does business-speak belong in the tag business-language?

Yes, it does. There's no prohibition against politely stating one's disagreement with the aesthetics or otherwise of such terms, though.